# Magento: use multiple select (open dropdown) insetad of drop down

Tags: php, magento, foreach, multi-select

Hi I am building a custom module and there is a part where you can select which store to extract the data out of, I can have it show with a dropdown (standard), but how can I change  it to a multi select box so you can select more than 1 store to get the data from, same with order status, it's currently drop down, but I like to be able to select more than 1 status.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you mean you want to be able to add this into the Magneto admin system, using the XML configuration.

You will want to add something like this into your field definitions

```
<select_store translate="label">
    <label>Pick stores here bla</label>
    <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
    <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_store</source_model>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
</select_store>
```

This should add a multiselect input, and gather all the stores for you. For help on the Magento config see here: http://alanstorm.com/custom_magento_system_configuration

Comment: thanks, how will  php process it, I could not use the foreachloop

Comment: no I actually was not talking about the Xml, i would have said xml if that is what i thought, seems like u don't know the answer but u just want to have something to say

Comment: I was trying to help you arrogant man, if you were more specific you may get better help.

Comment: In future you should post examples of the code you currently have to illustrate where your problem is, with a little more detail so you get the help you need.